# insert two list in sql whit python

Tags: python, mysql

Through web scraping, I get two lists, one is the name and the other is the price of a product. How can I enter these values in two columns at the same time so that the price of each product is in front of it?

```
import mysql.connector
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
list_esm=[]
list_gheymat=[]

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='vorodi')

cursor = cnx.cursor()



user = str(input())
url =('https://divar.ir/s/tehran?q=')
search = requests.get(url + user)
search.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(search.text, 'html.parser')
esm = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'kt-post-card__title'})
gheymat = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class':'kt-post-card__top-description'})
for i in esm:
    w = re.sub(r'\s+',' ',i.text).strip()
    list_esm.append(w) 
for i in gheymat:
    q= (re.sub(r'^\s*',' ' ,i.text).strip())
    list_gheymat.append(q)
query_1 = """INSERT INTO divar_2 (name,price) VALUES (%r,%r);""" %(tuple(list_esm),tuple(list_gheymat))
cursor.execute(query_1)
cnx.commit()




cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that both lists are of the same length you can just iterate over them:

```
for i in range(len(list_esm)):
    query_1 = """INSERT INTO divar_2 (name,price) VALUES (%r,%r);""" %(list_esm[i], list_gheymat[i])
    print(query_1)
```

Comment: zip would clearly make this for loop unnecessary and you can male a bulk insert